# Whither AVCaptureAudioFileOutput on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

The Internets don't seem to have an answer to this question.

In [this reference page for AVCaptureFileOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html), they state that:

> The concrete subclasses of AVCaptureFileOutput are
>   AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, which records media to a QuickTime movie
>   file, and AVCaptureAudioFileOutput, which writes audio media to a
>   variety of audio file formats.

It happens that I have an app that captures video in one feature, and audio only in another. So I am trying to set up an instance of the AVCaptureAudioFileOutput to accomplish that. However, it's not available in iOS! AVCaptureMovieFileOutput is present and accounted for; what am I supposed to do to record audio only?

Answer (score 4):

Forget about AVCaptureFileOutput and its descendent and instead use AVCaptureAudioDataOutput to capture audio buffers which you then write to an audio file (e.g. M4A or WAV) using an AVAssetWriter.